# Fubinis Theorem and integrable function

Tags: measure-theory

My question is can one use Fubinis theorem to show that a functions integral does not exist?

In the statement of fubinis theorem we have that if $f \in L^{1} (\mu \times v)$
Then $\int_{X \times E} f d_{\mu \times v} = \int_{X}(\int_{Y}fdv)d \mu = \int_{Y}(\int_{X}fd \mu)d v$.

If I understand it correctly a functions integral exist $\iff f\in L^{1}(\mu \times v) \iff \int|f|^{1} d \mu < \infty$
(is this true?)

So if I can show that $\int_{X}(\int_{Y}fdv)d \mu \neq \int_{Y}(\int_{X}fd \mu)d v$

Will it imply that $f \notin L^{1}(\mu \times v) \implies f$ is not integrable?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: If you get a very strange integral in this case, is there any other, better way to show that a function is not integrable?